# Lua error - MediaWiki templates

Tags: php, lua, mediawiki

After installing Scribunto (adding the extension to the folder and adding in LocalSettings the following code:)

```
require_once "$IP/extensions/Scribunto/Scribunto.php";
```

I have imported the Template:Infobox and Module:Infobox (along with the ones which come with those), and after testing a basic infobox I received the **Script error** -

> Lua error: Internal error. Error reading from pipe.

Afterwards, I have done some research and I added the following line (in LocalSettings):

```
$wgScribuntoEngineConf['luastandalone']['luaPath'] = '/binaries/lua5_1_4_Win64_bin/';
```

Then, the **Script error** changes to:

> Lua error: Internal error: The interpreter exited with status 1.

I use Windows 10. How can I fix this?